# How can I select password using keyboard shortcut on iPad

Tags: keyboard, ipad, magic-keyboard-ipad

I suppose the same keyboard shortcut would work on iPhones too.
I just want to use a keyboard shortcut to populate the password for a given website. I use BitWarden, but the password button I have to press is a generic one on the status/autocorrect bar.